# PHP echo cookie to console.log writing correctly in source but not in console

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies

I have a PHP function that uses $_GET to grab 'utm_source' from the URL and set it in a cookie.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['utm_src'])) {
    $utm_src = $_GET['utm_source'];
    setcookie("utm_src", $utm_src, 0, "/");
}
?>
```

This all happens before any HTML is sent through (in functions.php using Wordpress), and seems to be writing properly when I check the cookies after page load.

The issue occurs when I try to echo the variable into a javascript console.log in order to make sure everything is working properly:

```
<?php
$utm_src = $_COOKIE['utm_source'];
echo "<script>console.log('utm is $utm_src');</script>";
?>
```

The strange thing is that when I view source the script seems to be written correctly including the variable, yet not in the console.

This is what shows in the actual source after page load:

```
<script>
console.log('utm is utm-name-here');
</script>
```

However, the console only shows 'utm is ', with no variable. I was hoping to use the cookie variable to determine whether a script should be echo'd onto page or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing your cookie as `utm_src` and trying to access it as `utm_source`

Use the same name when setting the cookie and when reading the cookie and you'll get the result that you're hoping for.

Specifically

```
    $utm_src = $_COOKIE['utm_source'];
```

should be

```
    $utm_src = $_COOKIE['utm_src'];
```

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to still lead the same result. The js script is written correctly to the source, but the variables still show up blank within the Console.